How to fix: MODULE_NOT_FOUND in webpack
I am trying to run my development server in my React application I am getting an error on webpack module not being found
> login-car-insurance@1.0.0 start
> webpack serve --env.NODE_ENV=development --progress

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'T:\BKI\login-car-insurance\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.11.0

After trying npm install then npm start I get the error
I tried installing webpack using npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev then run** npm start** I am still getting the same error

show me your package.json
